# Reac Native - 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-rc01' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

```
   1.  Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-rc01' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.
 
       :app is currently compiled against android-33.
 
       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 7.2.1 is 32.
 
       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
 
       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

I tried updating the Gradle Plugin version and Gradle Version.
Gradle Plugin version is currently 7.2.1 and Gradle Version is 7.5.1.
The project was last run around 2 months ago and was working fine.

Comment: I am getting the same error.